# Volume Control for <embed>?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, embed

I have an audio element with JavaScript volume control. This works fine with HTML5 browsers, however, some browsers (like the most recent version of Safari, for example), require running an `<embed>` tag instead. I know with the `<audio>` tag, there's a volume property that can be accessed with JavaScript. Is there a volume property that can be accessed with JavaScript for the `<embed>` tag?

I tried the following, to no avail:

```
<embed src="blablah.mp3" id="audio1"><span id='Volume_Up'>Volume Up</span>

<script>
document.getElementById('Volume_Up').addEventListener('click',Volume_Up_Function,true);

function Volume_Up_Function(){

    document.getElementById('audio1').volume++;

}
</script>
```